# C# 2 dispositivos Input de data tipo teclado( quiero ingresar cada dispositvo en diferente variable)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Buen dia

Bueno empezemos esta es la situacion tengo dos dispositivos una es una bascula y el otro dispositivo mide superficie pero y tengo que hacer una interfaz en C# y los dos al conectarlos a la compu se detectan como puerto USB y no como puerto COM, por lo que la informacion la lee como tipo teclado (como lo que hacen tambien los Scaneers) entonces lo que quiero hacer es que la data de cada dispositivo se muestre en un textbox o label, pero no se como diferenciar uno de otro en la programacion, me di cuenta que el dispositivo 1 cuando jala la data se escribe mas rapido que el dispositivo 2, entonces pense que una forma seria diferenciarlos por su velocidad de escritura , ( porque por formato no se puede debido a que tienen el punto decimal en el mismo lugar y el tamaño de caracteres igual) otra forma era de que tambien me di cuenta que el dispositivo 1 al leer la data brinca al siguiente renglon y el dispositivo 2 se mantiene en el mismo renglon por lo que pense en que el programa cheque cual de los dos es de 1 o 2 renglones y asi diferenciarlos.

Les agradeceria si me pudieran ayudar con la logica de las maneras que pense o si tienen alguna otra forma de diferenciarlos me digan.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: la info que envia cada dispositivo se puede configurar ? lo pregunto porque podria agregarse algun prefijo fijo junto a la lectura que permita determinar quien envia ese dato. En lugar de tener el foco en un textbox para la lectura se podria usar las api de windows para capturar las lecturas de teclado

Comment: no se puede que yo sepa y si se puede no se como hacerlo

Comment: contactaste con el fabricante de estos dispositivos ? ademas de quizas darte alguna idea en la configuracion, quizas el fabricante dispone de librerias que puedas usar para la lectura

Comment: Nunca, nunca, **nunca**, tomes información arbitraira como la velocidad de escritura o formato de datos de entrada para distinguir dispositivos; esta información puede variar por motivos fuera de tu control (velocidad de tu cpu) o entre versiones de dispositivos. La manera de diferenciarlos es **leer el manual del dispositivo**, en el manual te debería detallar cómo cada dispositivo se comunica con el sistema.